# web api though Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net-web-api

i have got the bellow simple api

```java
public class ProductRepository : IProductPrpository
{

    #region IProductPrpository Members

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll(string ProductOption)
    {
        return Utility.GetDiscountItems(ProductOption);
    }

    public Product GetProduct(string Id)
    {
        return Utility.GetProduct(Id);
    }
    public String PostBag(Bag bagofItem)
    {
       return  Utility.PostBagDiscountedItem(bagofItem);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

it is working fine when i call GetProduct &  GetProduct but when post for PostBag it through the Method Not Allowed -

```
http://localhost:54460/api/products?PostBag="
```

error 
please help

there is my client side script which post data to PostBag Api

```html
@model List<MultiBuy.Models.Product>

 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

 <h2>Items in the bag</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
    <th> Item_number_option&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </th>
    <th> Option_number &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </th>
    <th> Price &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>    
    <th> PublicationCode &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>    
    <th> Quantity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </th>   

  </tr>

   @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <tr>
         <td> @item.ItemNumber</td>
         <td> @item.Option</td>
         <td> @item.Price</td>
         <td> @item.PublicationCode</td>
         <td> @item.Quantity</td>

      </tr>
   }   
 </table>
 <div>
 <ul id="products" />
  <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();"  />
  </div>
 @section scripts {
 <script>
  function find() {
  var dataJSON = '@Model';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://locallhost:54460/api/products?PostBag=',

            data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#products').text(data)
        });
    };

</script>
}
```

appreciate all your help

Answer (score -1):

You can not make a post in the same way you do the get, Get you can put parameters in your url, but Post you can´t.

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Comment: SORRY STILL ITS NOT WORKING I HAVE CHANGE TO CODE TO $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:54460/api/products?PostBag=' + JSON.stringify(dataJSON) BUT THE ERROR MES NOW http://localhost:54460/api/products?PostBag=%22System.Collections.Generic.List%601[MultiBuy.Models.Product]%22"

Comment: But u have to do like :

$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
 url: 'localhost:54460/api/products', 
data:{"PostBag":JSON.stringify(dataJSON) }

Comment: There are some complications but you definitely can use URI parameters with POST.

Comment: ok now it through a new error "ReferenceError: data is not defined" but the dataJSAON ='@Model' which is a list<products>